# How to disable pointer-events, but allow drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm trying to create a sidebar menu for the mobile web page. My goal is to slide-out side-bar from 25% of screens left edge.

[image: Sidebar menu drag target]

A similar way is used in [Materialize frameworks Sidenav](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html)

`#drag-target` is used to receive drag events and slide-out sidebar. 
Problem is that `#drag-target` covers part of the content and blocks click/touch events on underlying elements.

I used CSS rule `pointer-events: none` but this breaks swipe on the element itself.

Is there any way to pass touch/click events through the `#drag-target` on all underlying elements, except swipe/drag?

Comment: `Problem is that #drag-target covers part of the content and blocks click/touch events on underlying elements` -> not clear, you couldn't use something like `z-index` ? or Am I wrong?

Comment: @Pedram, `#drag-target` is transparent and invisible. It should be over left 25% of all body content and receive swipe gestures to slide-out sidebar. If I move target with `z-index` behind the content, then I will have the same issue: it will not receive swipe gestures, because the content will cover `#drag-target`

Comment: Now, I get it what happened. You used `jQuery Mobile` for swipe? or what?

Comment: I use Hummer.js for gestures

Comment: Can you share `drag-target` styles?

Comment: After use `pointer-events: none` can use underlying elements? `pointer-events` will disable all mouse actions, not anything with element!

Comment: Yes after applying ‘pointer-events: none’ underlying elements are clickable, but no event is catchable with ‘drag-target’. So I’m searching for different solution.

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: Maybe you could get rid of the `#drag-target` entirely, and pick up the drag events on the underlying container. Then check the data of the event, and ignore it if it didn't start in the left 25% area.

Comment: @suddjian thats exactly what I did after some time. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not possible to catch events with `pointer-events: none` applied, I ran to another way by handling events on the whole body and manually sliding side-bar.

After struggling with `Hammer.js` I came with working side-bar but found out that, Hammer has a little bug with `Pan` events and sometimes event was giving incorrect delta. So I decided to listen to basic `TouchEvents`.

Here is the result if it will be helpful to anyone: https://codepen.io/pen/xxbNwmX

> *P.S. Test it from Touch-enabled devices or browser emulator*

```js
/**
 * @class Sidenav
 * @constructor
 */
class Sidenav {
 /**
  * @param wrapper {String | jQuery}
  * @param sidenav {String | jQuery}
  * @param [hitArea] {number}
  * @param [threshold] {number}
  */
 constructor (wrapper, sidenav, hitArea = .20, threshold = 20) {
  // settings
  this.wrapper = wrapper
  this.sidenav = sidenav
  this.hitArea = window.innerWidth * hitArea
  this.threshold = threshold
  this.width = $(sidenav).width()
  this.isHitarea = false
  this._state = 'closed'
  this.states = 'open closed open-started close-started'
  this.touchStart = 0
  
  // touch start
  $(this.wrapper).on('touchstart', (e) => {
   let touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]
   this.touchStart = touch.pageX
   this.isHitarea = this.touchStart < this.hitArea
  })
  
  // touch move
  $(this.wrapper).on('touchmove', (e) => {
   let touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]
   let delta = touch.pageX - this.touchStart
   this.slide(delta)
  })
  
  // touch end
  $(this.wrapper).on('touchend', (e) => {
   let touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]
   let delta = touch.pageX - this.touchStart
   
   if (this.state == 'open-started') {
    this.state = Math.abs(delta) >= this.width / 4 ? 'open' : 'closed'
   }
   else if (this.state == 'close-started') {
    this.state = Math.abs(delta) >= this.width / 4 ? 'closed' : 'open'
   }
  })
  
 }
 
 /** @param st {String} */
 set state (st) {
  this._state = st
  
  // remove all classes
  $(this.wrapper).removeClass(this.states).addClass(st)
 }
 
 get state () {
  return this._state
 }
 
 slide (delta) {
  switch (this.state) {
   case 'closed':
    if (this.isHitarea && delta >= this.threshold) {
     this.state = 'open-started'
     this.move(delta - this.threshold)
    }
    break
   case 'open-started':
    this.move(delta - this.threshold)
    break
   case 'open':
    if (delta < 0 && Math.abs(delta) > this.threshold) {
     this.state = 'close-started'
     let translate = Math.max(-this.width, delta + this.threshold)
     this.move(translate, 1)
    }
    break
   case 'close-started':
    let translate = Math.min(Math.max(-this.width, delta + this.threshold), 0)
    this.move(translate, 1)
    break
  }
 }
 
 move (delta, left = false) {
  if (left) {
   $(this.wrapper).css('transform', `translateX(${delta}px)`)
  }
  else {
   $(this.wrapper).css('transform', `translateX(${Math.min(-this.width + delta, 0)}px)`)
  }
 }
}


// run
$(function() {
 let sidenav = new Sidenav('.wrapper', '.sidenav')
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}

body {
    background-color: #202126;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    color: antiquewhite
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    touch-action: pan-x !important;
    transform: translateX(-240px)
}

.wrapper .sidenav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    color: #202126;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px
}

.wrapper .content {
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(240px);
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

.wrapper .content button {
    padding: 10px
}

.wrapper.open {
    transform: translateX(0) !important;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out
}

.wrapper.closed {
    transform: translateX(-240px) !important;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper closed">
  <div class="sidenav">
    <h2>SIDENAV</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <br>
    <button onclick="alert('Click click!')">Clickable button</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus assumenda consequatur debitis doloribus, dolorum esse incidunt nobis obcaecati omnis possimus quasi, quidem recusandae reiciendis rerum tempora unde velit vitae voluptates.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus assumenda consequatur debitis doloribus, dolorum esse incidunt nobis obcaecati omnis possimus quasi, quidem recusandae reiciendis rerum tempora unde velit vitae voluptates.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus assumenda consequatur debitis doloribus, dolorum esse incidunt nobis obcaecati omnis possimus quasi, quidem recusandae reiciendis rerum tempora unde velit vitae voluptates.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus assumenda consequatur debitis doloribus, dolorum esse incidunt nobis obcaecati omnis possimus quasi, quidem recusandae reiciendis rerum tempora unde velit vitae voluptates.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus assumenda consequatur debitis doloribus, dolorum esse incidunt nobis obcaecati omnis possimus quasi, quidem recusandae reiciendis rerum tempora unde velit vitae voluptates.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus assumenda consequatur debitis doloribus, dolorum esse incidunt nobis obcaecati omnis possimus quasi, quidem recusandae reiciendis rerum tempora unde velit vitae voluptates.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus assumenda consequatur debitis doloribus, dolorum esse incidunt nobis obcaecati omnis possimus quasi, quidem recusandae reiciendis rerum tempora unde velit vitae voluptates.</p>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comment, it should work with `z-index` now here, in my example, you can bring `drag-target` behind the elements, and in this situation, button action and also `swipe` action both works perfectly *!* check this out, and compare with your code. And do not use `pointer-events: none` becuase it disable **all** mouse functions *!*

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  alert('button action!')
});

var myElement = document.getElementById('drag-target');
var Hammer = new Hammer(myElement);

Hammer.on("swipe", function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.type)
  alert('come out and play!')
});
```

```css
#drag-target {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js" integrity="sha256-GMd3rFxMDNnM5JQEpiKLLl8kSrDuG5egqchk758z59g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <button>Button</button>
  <div id="drag-target"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually this method is not exactly what I want to achieve, because in some cases when you swipe on button or text, which is over `drag-item`, swipe is not triggered. I guess I have to add a swipe listener to the whole body and then manually calculate delta. I thought there would be a less complex way. Thanks anyway.